# At Schiphol, is 1 hour 50 minutes enough time to transfer to KLM Cityhopper from EasyJet?

Tags: airport-transfer, short-connections, ams, klm, easyjet

I'm flying into Schiphol at 2:30 pm on Monday April 18th via Easyjet from Prague. Then I'm hoping to fly out on a KLM Cityhopper flight at 4:20pm to Newcastle. That leaves me 1 hour 50 minutes for taxiing, fetching luggage, checking in to KLM, security, and walking to the gate.

Does anyone know if that sounds reasonable? If not I can get a later flight but that will involve hanging around the airport for 6+ hours. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [At Schiphol is 55 minutes enough for a transfer to an EasyJet flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53060/at-schiphol-is-55-minutes-enough-for-a-transfer-to-an-easyjet-flight)

Comment: I would say that Q is not a duplicate, non of the answers there do answer this question, just enough difference that they are not useful.

Comment: You can also use these 6 hours to relax, eat dinner and do some tax free shopping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it is likely possible but it is fairly short.
It often takes more than 15 minutes between landing and getting to the airport buildings. EasyJet does not often use bus transport from the plane to the building but it can happen. And when it does it may add more time.
As you say you will need to leave the secure area of the airport, collect your luggage and go through luggage drop off, passport control and security.

Waiting for your luggage should not take too much time, but 10 minutes is the least to expect.

Most of the time non of the lines on the way in will be long, but three times 10 minutes will eat up most of your time. And it is not unlikely there are more delays when things go wrong.

Add the walking times, and you are almost out of time without any delays.

EasyJet can be late, they do not promise to get you there on the minute, just to get you there. With the later flight out of Schiphol, a delay of a few hours will not be a problem, but with the early flight a 30 minute delay can be too much.

I would go for the later flight, 6 hours in Schiphol is not too bad. If it is more than 6 hours you might consider going out of the airport if your incomming flight is on time.

I guess KLM city hopper will not allow you to change to a later flight without paying costs if the EasyJet flight is late.
If the tickets are cheap you could buy a ticket for both the early and a later flight.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking but was curious if I was just being too cautious. Thanks for the advice. :) I'm gonna book the later flight.

Comment: You do not have to pass passport control on the way out, so this will not happen to you, but last time I flew it took most of an hour rather than the usual 10 minutes to get through passport control, due to technical problems on a busy day, that is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that you're transferring between different airlines on different tickets.  This means you need to allow enough time for things to go wrong.

If both flights are on the same ticket, and a delay to the first flight causes you to miss the second, the airline is responsible. They must put you onto a new flight at no extra cost and, in some cases, with compensation for the delay. However, when the second flight is on a separate ticket, you are responsible for presenting yourself at the airport early enough to catch that flight.  If EasyJet gets you into Schiphol late, that's tough luck and you'll have to buy a new KLM ticket, just as you would if you'd missed your flight because you overslept.

Further issues to take into account are that, as you're aware, you'll have to recheck your luggage and so on. Also, bear in mind that EasyJet flights to Schiphol often board by bus from a remote part of the airfield, so it may take quite some time even to get to the terminal building.

Long story short: 1hr 50mins is probably enough time if everything works perfectly.  If things don't work almost perfectly, you'll miss your connection and have to buy a new ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise taking the later flight, rather than risking the long lines at Schiphol.

Especially as there is no liability on the airlines to wait for you if you are late, as you are on two separate tickets.

Besides, 6 hours is nothing in Schiphol. You can also do a quick stop over in Amsterdam for some lunch/dinner and comfortably make it back.